# How to get value out of a ion-select in a nested ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor, ngmodel

As the title states. I have a nested `ngFor` loop in my html. I am using one of these `ngFor` loops in a `ion-select` statement. Here is my code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of pageOptions" >
      <ion-label>{{item.attender.FIRST_NAME}} {{item.attender.LAST_NAME}}</ion-label>
      <ion-select multiple="true">
        <ion-option value="item" *ngFor="let item of item.options">{{item.ATTENDER_NAME}} ${{item.PARTICIPANT_PRICE}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the value out of `*ngFor="let item of item.options"` using `[(ngModel)]`.

Can anyone help me figure out this conundrum?
I got asked for my data. I have an array that I am pushing this object into: `let item = { attender: member, options: [{}] };` The options portion gets a JSON object pushed into it. This might not even be possible.

Here is the total build of the data:

```js
this.attenders = this.clickedItem.attenders;
      this.attenderOptions = this.clickedItem.activityDefinition.ATTENDERS; //this might not be ATTENDERS
      this.positionOptions = this.clickedItem.activityDefinition.POSITIONS;
      this.guests = this.clickedItem.guests;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.attenders.length; i++) {
        let item = {
          attender: this.attenders[i],
          options: []
        };
        for (var j = 0; j < this.attenderOptions.length; j++) {
          let minAge = this.attenderOptions[j].MIN_PARTICIPANT_AGE;
          let maxAge = this.attenderOptions[j].MAX_PARTICIPANT_AGE;
          let minGrade = this.attenderOptions[j].MIN_PARTICIPANT_GRADE;
          let maxGrade = this.attenderOptions[j].MAX_PARTICIPANT_GRADE;
          let availablePositions = this.attenderOptions[j].AVAILABLE_POSITIONS;
          var birthdate = this.convertBirth(this.attenders[i].BIRTH_DAY, this.attenders[i].BIRTH_MONTH, this.attenders[i].BIRTH_YEAR)
          var gradeString = this.attenders[i].GRADE;
          var grade = this.convertGrade(gradeString);
          if (availablePositions > 0) {
            if ((this.compareMinDates(birthdate, minAge) && this.compareMaxDates(birthdate, maxAge)) || (this.compareMinGrades(grade, minGrade) && this.compareMaxGrades(grade, maxGrade))) {
              //within age constraints
              item.options.push(this.attenderOptions[j]);
            } else if (minAge == "" && maxAge == "" && minGrade == "" && maxGrade == "") {
              item.options.push(this.attenderOptions[j]);
            }
          }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < this.positionOptions.length; j++) {
          if (this.positionOptions[i] != undefined) {
            let minAge = this.positionOptions[j].MIN_PARTICIPANT_AGE;
            let maxAge = this.positionOptions[j].MAX_PARTICIPANT_AGE;
            let minGrade = this.positionOptions[j].MIN_PARTICIPANT_GRADE;
            let maxGrade = this.positionOptions[j].MAX_PARTICIPANT_GRADE;
            let availablePositions = this.positionOptions[j].POSITIONS_REMAINING;
            var birthdate = this.convertBirth(this.attenders[i].BIRTH_DAY, this.attenders[i].BIRTH_MONTH, this.attenders[i].BIRTH_YEAR)
            var gradeString = this.attenders[i].GRADE;
            var grade = this.convertGrade(gradeString);
            if (availablePositions >= 0) {
              if ((this.compareMinDates(birthdate, minAge) && this.compareMaxDates(birthdate, maxAge)) || (this.compareMinGrades(grade, minGrade) && this.compareMaxGrades(grade, maxGrade))) {
                //within age constraints
                this.positionOptions[i].ATTENDER_NAME = this.positionOptions[i].POSITION_NAME;
                this.positionOptions[i].PARTICIPANT_PRICE = 0;
                item.options.push(this.positionOptions[j]);
              } else if (minAge == "" && maxAge == "" && minGrade == "" && maxGrade == "") {
                this.positionOptions[i].ATTENDER_NAME = this.positionOptions[i].POSITION_NAME;
                this.positionOptions[i].PARTICIPANT_PRICE = 0;
                item.options.push(this.positionOptions[j]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        this.pageOptions.push(item);
      }
```

Comment: You want to get the value out of *ngFor="let item of item.options" & give it to which variable ?

Comment: It would help if you posted how your data looks like. It can easily be achieved with a separate variable like in provided answer, but if you are looking for "something else", please clarify and show us the build of data :)

Comment: I have edited it. Take a look at the original post!

Comment: Whoa, too much code, what I was looking for was a console log of your data, i.e `pageOptions` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of pageOptions" >
  <ion-label>{{item.attender.FIRST_NAME}} {{item.attender.LAST_NAME}}</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="select"  multiple="true">
    <ion-option value="item" *ngFor="let item of item.options">{{item.ATTENDER_NAME}} ${{item.PARTICIPANT_PRICE}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue with that is when I select an option on one of the attenders, it populates every person. What if I want to pick an option for one person and then a different option for the other person. Here is my data: `let item = {
            attender: member,
            options: [{}]
          };`